# Línea en medio de eje X y Y en chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Estoy haciendo una gráfica en charjs Bubble y necesito hacer que de manera automática se ponga una línea horizontal en medio del eje X y una linea vertical en eje Y, según voy variando datos en data[x,y]. Agradesco su apoyo, este es mi código "script" de lo que pude avanzar.

```js
<script>
var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.bubble.prototype.draw;

Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.bubble.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

var chart = this.chart;
var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
if (index) {
  var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
  var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xaxis.left, yaxis.getPixelForValue(index, undefined));
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
  ctx.lineTo(xaxis.right, yaxis.getPixelForValue(index, undefined));
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();
}
  }
});
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var BubleVentanaGanadora = new Chart(ctx,{

type: 'bubble',
data: {
  datasets: [
    {
      label: ["China"],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(255,221,50,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255,221,50,1)",
      data: [{
        x: 9017,
        y: 60,
        r: 15
      }]
    }, {
      label: ["Denmark"],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(60,186,159,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(60,186,159,1)",
      data: [{
        x: 2702,
        y: 50,
        r: 10
      }]
    }
  ],lineAtIndex: 30
},
  "options": {
 "title": { display: true, text: 'Indicadores'},
 "tooltips": { mode: 'point',},
"scales": {
  "yAxes": [{
    "ticks": {
      "beginAtZero": true,                        
              },
      //"scaleLabel": { display: true, labelString: 'MONTO'},
       "gridLines": { borderDash: [2, 5]}

  }],
  "xAxes": [{ scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Monto'},
  "ticks": {
      "beginAtZero": true,                        
              },
    }]
}
  }

});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

[image: adjunto captura del resultado que tengo del script]

Comment: El tipo de gráfico debe ser line no bubble

Comment: Es necesario que el grafico sea bubble, gracias.